# Create htpasswd for cwp login

Tags: security, centos, cwp

I want to create a htpasswd file for cwp login with root privileges but I got

```
htpasswd: cannot create file .htpasswd
```

and I can't change permission of admin folder or create a file in this folder
my command
`sudo htpasswd -c /usr/local/cwpsrv/htdocs/admin/.htpasswd username`

any idea?